# Python - Writing slice function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, slice

I'm trying to write a function that will slice a list between two given values. If the stop value exceeds the list bounds, the stop value is the length of the list. If the start value exceeds the list bounds, I want to return an empty list. If the start value is less than the stop value, I want to return an empty list. I do not want to use any built-in functions or methods other than `range()` and `list.append()`

The code that is calling the function is:

```
str_list = ['s', 'h', 'r', 'u', 'g', 'g', 'e', 'd']

print("\nget_slice Test")
my_slice = list_function.get_slice(str_list, 2, 100)
print(list_function.to_string(str_list))
print(list_function.to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = list_function.get_slice(str_list, 6, 1)
print(list_function.to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = list_function.get_slice(str_list, 2, 5)
print(list_function.to_string(str_list))
print(list_function.to_string(my_slice))
```

The output I want to produce is:

```
get_slice Test
List is: s, h, r, u, g, g, e, d
List is: r, u, g, g, e, d
List is:
List is: s, h, r, u, g, g, e, d
List is: r, u, g
```

I'm defining the function as:

```
def get_slice(my_list, start, stop):
```

I've tried `my_list = my_list[start:stop]` but I get a 'NoneType' object is not iterable error. I also wanted to try using `for k in range(0, length(my_list)):`, as it was suggested that I use `range()`, however I can't think of a way that could be used for this function just yet.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hint: look at `range(start, stop)`....

Comment: Why are you doing that, when Python already supports slice notation? Is it homework? Learning? What have you tried so far? Show some code.

Comment: Please show your attempts! Also, show your expected input.

Comment: I've tried `my_list = my_list[start:stop]` but I get a 'NoneType' object is not iterable error. I also wanted to try using `for k in range(0, length(my_list)):`, as it was suggested that I use `range()`, however I can't think of a way that could be used for this function just yet.

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempts, so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the slice notation. That was covered here in this thread:

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Here is the solution printing the correct output:

```
def get_slice(my_list, start, stop):
        return my_list[start:stop][:]

def to_string(my_list):
        return 'List is: %s' % ''.join(my_list[:])

str_list = ['s', 'h', 'r', 'u', 'g', 'g', 'e', 'd']

print("\nget_slice Test")
my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 2, 100)
print(to_string(str_list))
print(to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 6, 1)
print(to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 2, 5)
print(to_string(str_list))
print(to_string(my_slice))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your problem, you should have posted the full code. Maybe a missing return and a fix on the variables? I don't know. But here's my solution:

```
def get_slice(my_list, start, stop):
    return my_list[start:stop]

def to_string(my_list):
    return "List is: " + ', '.join(my_list)

str_list = ['s', 'h', 'r', 'u', 'g', 'g', 'e', 'd']

print("\nget_slice Test")
my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 2, 100)
print(to_string(str_list))
print(to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 6, 1)
print(to_string(my_slice))

my_slice = get_slice(str_list, 2, 5)
print(to_string(str_list))
print(to_string(my_slice))
```

output:

```
get_slice Test
List is: s, h, r, u, g, g, e, d
List is: r, u, g, g, e, d
List is: 
List is: s, h, r, u, g, g, e, d
List is: r, u, g
```